# CodeBlocks C++ Display how many numbers i have typed in

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to make it, so lets say i type in 654321, it would say that i typed in 6 numbers.
I need to make it so it counts how many numbers i have typed in, and would display so.
Looking for anyone who could do that for me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your number entered as an integer or a string?

Comment: What you should do is post your own attempt at solving this problem, then you'll get help in fixing it. What you won't get is someone doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your entered number is an integer, you can setup a counter variable to count the number of digits and then divide the number by 10 and subsequently increment count in a loop:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    long long num;
    int count = 0;
    std::cin>> num;
    do
    {   count++;
        num /= 10;
    } while(num != 0);

    std::cout<< count;
}
```

Use long long for large input.

If your entered number is a string, then you can use `stoi()` to convert it into an integer.

Comment: Thanks, i had to change it a bit, sorry i didn't add my own attempt at it. http://cpp.sh/8r4bd

Comment: * http://cpp.sh/7tkam